# Template from which Python was called

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

Is there a way to pass or detect the name of the template from which the Python (Flask) function was executed?

For example, I have a form in my base template `base.html` which can be submitted in any other loaded template. When I submit that form in, for example `template_x.html`, and process it in Python I need to render another template. Since I do not know from which template the form was submitted, I need to somehow detect or pass its ID to Python so that I could then render `template_x.html`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [this](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/tricks/#highlighting-active-menu-items) trick. In your `base.html`'s form, add a hidden element:

```
<input type="hidden" name="current_template" value="{{ current_template }}" />
```

And in your `template_x.html` which extends the `base.html` just add this line (outside of any block):

```
{% set current_template = 'template_x.html' %}
```

It's working because assignments outside of blocks in child templates are global and executed before the layout template is evaluated.

Comment: Thank you! This is just what I've needed :)